# Lost connection to MySQL server during query. when other queries are working smoothly

Tags: mysql, database-connection, freeze

Every time when I run the below query, server freezes and after canceling the query I'm receiving the following error message:

`[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

My query:

```
UPDATE products.products
SET state = 'BOUGHT'
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT
            s.aid
        FROM
            log.log
        LEFT JOIN shop.shop s ON (s.id = log.who)
        WHERE
            product_id = 171054
        AND action = 'BUY'
        GROUP BY
            log.`who`
        HAVING
            COUNT(log.who) > 2
    );
```

Could someone help me with that? Other queries and two servers are generating hundreds of queries per second and they did not freeze, everything is working smooth except this query.

Comment: You need to give people more information to help them answer your question. Like the schema, the execution plan of your query, the number of rows in your tables, etc. Having just the query to work with is hard.